# Random choice on python file not working

Tags: python

I am trying to do a flash card quiz challenge in Python. This involves taking the states and their capitals from a text file. I've managed to strip and split in order to create a dictionary with keys.

But everytime I use random choice within the for loop it outputs the last key (e.g. Wyoming) On the other hand, when I take it out of the for loop, it only outputs the first key (e.g. Alabama)

Here is what it looks like (obviously this doesn't show the text file)

```
import random
with open("state_capitals.txt","r") as f:
for line in f:
    cleanedLine = line.strip().split(',')
    state = cleanedLine[0]
    capital = cleanedLine[1]
    d = {}
    d[state] = capital
    while len(d)>0:
        choice = random.choice(list(d.keys()))

        print("What is the capital city of",choice,"?")
        answer=input("Answer:  ")
```

Comment: Don't recreate the dictionary from scratch for every line in the file. Make an empty dictionary, *then* add an item for each line.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've tried that (taking the while loop out of the for loop)

Comment: Thanks, sounds like I've got myself into a mess with this code. I might start from scratch and attempt to create a more efficient solution.

Comment: Not at all, this is a decent starting point and it's clear what you're trying to do. Just remove your 4 spaces of indentation from the `while len(d)>0:` onwards. Then just come up with a way to terminate that loop :)

Comment: The other issue is that `d = {}` is _inside_ the `for` loop so you keep resetting it to an empty dictionary every time. Cut/paste that line to be above `for line in f`

Comment: Thanks, I tried using break but with no success

Comment: I used pass and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have the `while` loop inside the scope of the `for` loop, so you never get a chance to populate your dictionary. However, moving the `while` loop outside of the `for` loop does not solve a different problem; you initialise `d` *within* the `for` loop, so that it keeps being reset back to an empty dictionary, removing all previous entries.

```
import random

d = {} # Create the dict once, otherwise each loop will delete all previous entries

with open("state_capitals.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        cleanedLine = line.strip().split(',')
        state = cleanedLine[0]
        capital = cleanedLine[1]
        d[state] = capital

# Move this outside the while loop. There's no need to recreate it on every iteration
states = list(d.keys())

# Move the while loop to be outside of the for loop
while len(d)>0:
    choice = random.choice(states)

    print("What is the capital city of",choice,"?")
    answer=input("Answer:  ")

    # Allow the user to type Quit/quit to break the loop
    if answer.lower() == 'quit':
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! this works too. I also moved the empty dict before for line in f and added pass to terminate the loop. That also worked!

Comment: @Corb691 you're welcome. If this has solved your issue, I would be grateful if you would consider [accepting this as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Corb691 Thanks. I've also made another small change. It is wise to generate your list of states only once. Therefore I moved it out of the `while` loop. While this probably has no noticeable effect on your code, if there were a billion items in that dictionary, you certainly wouldn't want to constantly keep generating the list of dictionary keys. If you allowed the user to enter more items into the dictionary, then you would have to regenerate the list of keys again within the loop, but only in response to new items being added.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while len(d) > 0` is inside the `for` loop, so during `choice = random.choice(list(d.keys()))` the dictionary has only one key. You also reinitialize the dictionary in every `for` loop iteration.